# Происхождение слова "цигейка"

Tags: этимология

Цигейка - это стриженная овечья шкура. А вот хотелось бы узнать происхождения этого слова.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цигейка ,как полагают, является словообразоват. переоформлением нем. Ziege «коза». Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

http://enc-dic.com/rusethy/Cigeka-5325.html